# How do I set the value of storeData from the React frontend?

Tags: solidity, react

Here's my solidity contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
  uint storedData;

  function set(uint x) public {
    storedData = x;
  }

  function get() public view returns (uint) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
```

And heres' the React frontend:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SimpleStorageContract from "./contracts/SimpleStorage.json";
import getWeb3 from "./getWeb3";

import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      // Get network provider and web3 instance.
      const web3 = await getWeb3();

      // Use web3 to get the user's accounts.
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

      // Get the contract instance.
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      const deployedNetwork = SimpleStorageContract.networks[networkId];
      const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        SimpleStorageContract.abi,
        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );

      // Set web3, accounts, and contract to the state, and then proceed with an
      // example of interacting with the contract's methods.
      this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance });
    } catch (error) {
      // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
      alert(
        `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`,
      );
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      storageValue: 0,
      web3: null, 
      accounts: null, 
      contract: null
    }
    this.setValue = this.setValue.bind(this);
  }

  setValue(x) {
    this.state.contract.methods.set(x).send({ from: this.state.accounts[0] });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.web3) {
      return <div>Loading Web3, accounts, and contract...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={(event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          let x;
          this.setValue(x);
        }}>
          <label>Enter value</label>
          <input type="text" ref={(input) => { this.x = input }}/>
          <button type="submit" >Set value</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I'm trying to set the value of storeData from the frontend, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

"to store data" in this context means sending transaction into the network, which would contain a call of `set` method of your `SimpleStorage` smart contract.

That would require calling `sendTransaction` https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction method of your web3 library signer with that call encoded in the `data` param